# Using Javascript if statement and onclick to trigger successive events

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want a shape to get bigger on one click of the mouse and bigger still on the next click of the mouse. Please can someone help ? I am a beginner so excuse the code being only partly thought out.

CSS:

```
#header.fullscreen{
  border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9999; 
     width: 350px;
    height: 350px;

    padding-top: 50px;
    align-content: center;

}
#header.fullscreen.bigger{
  border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9999; 
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    align-content: center;

}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#header').click(function(e){
    $('#header').toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
});

if ('#header.fullscreen' === true){
  $('#header.fullscreen').click(function(e){
    $('#header.fullscreen').toggleClass('bigger'); 
} else{

  //code here
}

</script>
```

Comment: `.toggle` will remove the `.bigger` class if it already exists and vice versa if it does not. You could use jQuery to increment the height/width of your element with `.css({ height: 123, width: 321 })`.

Comment: The `'#header.fullscreen'` selector will only target elements with the `fullscreen` class on them so you don't need the `if`. I'd use [delegation to make it work better](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). `$(document).on("click", "#header.fullscreen", function () { $(this).toggleClass("bigger"); });`

Comment: `$('#header.fullscreen')[0].width += 100;`